How to Determine if Two Shifts Overlap in C#?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to determine whether two shifts overlap in C#. Each shift is represented by a ShiftType class, containing start and end hours.
Here's an example of the ShiftType class:
public class ShiftType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int StartHour { get; set; }
    public int EndHour { get; set; }
}

I need to write a method that checks if two shifts overlap. For instance, if shift A starts at 6 and ends at 14, and shift B starts at 14 and ends at 22, they don't overlap. However, if shift C starts at 22 and ends at 7 (crosses midnight), it overlaps with shift A because it extends into the next day.
I've attempted to implement a method using comparisons of start and end hours, but I'm struggling to handle cases where one shift extends into the next day. How can I properly implement this functionality to accurately determine if two shifts overlap?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The Id field suggests this data might be stored in a database. Is that true? If so, which database and what .net library are you using to access it?

You could add this method to your class:
public bool OverlapsWith(ShiftType other)
{
    bool thisIsNightShift = StartHour > EndHour;
    bool otherIsNightShift = other.StartHour > other.EndHour;
    if (thisIsNightShift == otherIsNightShift) // either both true or false
    {
        return StartHour < other.EndHour && EndHour > other.StartHour;
    }
    else
    {
        return StartHour < other.EndHour || EndHour > other.StartHour;
    }
}

Tested with your samples and worked as desired:
ShiftType a = new ShiftType() { Id = "1", StartHour = 6, EndHour = 14 };
ShiftType b = new ShiftType() { Id = "2", StartHour = 14, EndHour = 22 };
ShiftType c = new ShiftType() { Id = "3", StartHour = 22, EndHour = 7 };
bool aOverlapsWithB = a.OverlapsWith(b); // false
bool aOverlapsWithC = a.OverlapsWith(c); // true
bool cOverlapsWithA = c.OverlapsWith(a); // true
bool cOverlapsWithB = c.OverlapsWith(b); // false

